# pwd command returns "/" after shifting API to HTTPS

Tags: bash, flask, https, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have created an API using *Apche2 mod_wsgi Flask*. The API has *python* & *shell script* components. The initial version of the API was *HTTP*, but now I have added *HTTPS* support as well.

When I am hitting the API via HTTP (http://myapi.mydomain.com/app/apiEndPOint), everything works smoothly. Here `pwd` command returns `/var/www` as the present working directory. But when I hit the API via HTTPS (https://myapi.mydomain.com/app/apiEndPOint), it couldn't find different modules (hence it throws errors) because of `pwd` command returns `/` as the present working directory.

Why is this happening? I faced the similar problem with python (os.getcwd()) but solved it using an alternate method. But the `pwd` command problem I couldn't solve.

Any clues/solutions to this problem?

Comment: You should not rely on the current working directory being a specific directory in applications hosted in a web server. Calculate your paths as an absolute path when you need to refer to anything in the file system. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory

Comment: BTW, you should show you mod_wsgi configuration for both HTTP and HTTPS ``VirtualHost``, as the fact they are different possibly means you haven't set them in a way that agrees. For WSGI applications which use HTTP and HTTPS, you should use a common mod_wsgi daemon process group, which each ``VirtualHost`` is set up to use.